# Inconsistency in reputation league and Users' tab

Tags: bug, reputation

When I click the [Users' tab](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users), I am apparently ranked #2 for the month:

[image]

But When I click [Stack Exchange User Reputation league](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/82/month/scifi) page, I am ranked #12 for the month:

[image]

What gives?

What I have been able to deduce is that Rep league page is not updated as of now while the tab page is realtime data, making it more accurate.

Is that what it is?

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: @Valorum There you go again, taking the easy answer ;)